# How to access an object's property through its interface in C#

Tags: c#, oop

I have a class A with a property A.A and a class B with a property B.B. Both implement the IC interface that enforces the IC.C property, but do not A.A or B.B.

I want a method that receive an instance of A or B as a parameter and can access those properties, something like:

```
void MyMethod(IC obj)
{
    if (obj.GetType().Name.Equals("A"))
    {
        var v = obj.A;    // some code for access the property
    }
}
```

Is that possible? And, is it a good idea?
Thanks!

Edited: renaming the interface as IC as suggested by @dmedine.

Comment: You could but it would be better to have two `MyMethod` on that takes in `A` as a parameter and one that takes in `B` as a parameter.

Comment: Don't do that. If the method expects an interface `ISomething` it *shouldn't* try to access methods that may not exist at all. Trying to do so is a clear bug. It means that either the interface was wrong and needs more members, that the *method* is wrong and tries to do the wrong thing, or that the classes are wrong

Comment: What are you trying to do? What are the *actual* types, actual methods? There are probably better ways to achieve what you want. You could use overloading and have different methods with the same name handle different types. Or use multiple interfaces. There may be other options too

Comment: I echo every other comment, but I'd like to add this: Don't test for the type of something by using a string comparison with `GetType().Name`.  Use the `is` operator or something else that doesn't require strings.

Comment: I'm playing around with object-oriented programming concepts, actually. I'm trying to avoid code duplication and just unify two methods that receive two instances that differ by only two properties. I was trying to figure out a way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach would depend on the specifics of what you are trying to do, but here are 2 options:

Pattern matching

```
void MyMethod(C obj)
{
    if (obj is A objAsA)
    {
        var vA = objAsA.A;
    }

    if (obj is B objAsB)
    {
        var vB = objAsB.B;
    }
}
```

Reflection

```
void MyMethod(C obj)
{
    var objType = obj.GetType();
    if (objType.Name.Equals("A"))
    {
        var prop = objType.GetProperty("A");
        var v = prop.GetValue(obj, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just wondering, why would one ever prefer reflection over pattern matching? Seems to me they accomplish exactly the same thing only pattern matching is more modern/readable/succinct (i.e. better).

Comment: @dmedine I don't think it is preferable assuming you can use pattern matching, but OP's question is a bit vague and perhaps more about learning what options are available. In reality they might be better off with generic methods or changing the class interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Doing this can, in my opinion, be useful under certain circumstances. For instance, if you have a bunch of objects that inherit from interface `IC` (always start the name of an interface with I) that have similar but also unique properties/methods (can't wait for the comments to roll in). You can test the type of class that inherits using `is`. For example, assuming `A` and `B` implement `IC`:

```
void MyMethod(List<IC> objects)
{
    foreach(IC object in objects) 
    {
        var cProperty = object.CProperty;  // use common property
        if(object is A a)
            var aProperty = a.AProperty;  // if A, use unique property
    }
}

void Foo()
{
    List<IC> cObjects = new();
    cObjects.Add(new A());
    cObjects.Add(new B());
    MyMethod(cObjects);
}
```